# Are tracking cookies from facebook, google, etc sneaked into open source projects?

Tags: node.js, privacy

In my node.js project, I'm using a several open source libraries and frameworks like - express, express-session, bootstrap 4.x etc.

I also have NGINX setup as reverse proxy. For this app's website, I do not have any tracking added by google, facebook or anyone for that matter.

Yet, when I open a random page of my website (not logged in yet) in chrome and look under "Applications" of Developer tools, I see several cookies:

_fbp, _gid, _ga, __stripe_mid, _hubspotutk, __hssrc, __hstc

(see screenshot)

Domain column hidden as they're all for my apps domain.

I have added FB Pixel and google analytics in the past, so I know how it would look like when added.

but for this project, I have NOT added it anywhere in my project files.

This has me really worried. Is there any way to figure out which package (prefererably file) had the code for these cookies ?
[image: UnSolicited Tracking cookies]

Comment: Do you have any other sites using the same domain?

Comment: No, no other sites are using that domain. No other domains on this VM either.

Comment: You can work out which requests are setting those cookies by clearing them, reloading the page, and looking at all the responses to see where they come from.

Comment: Thanks @Synchro. I just cleared the cookies and now I don't see cookies re-appear on any of the pages. I'll play around with this and see what I can find. If there is continued cause for concern then I'll update this post with my findings.

For now, I'm not sure where those cookies came from in the first place.